# spreadsheet embeded chart chartType error

Tags: google-visualization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the embeddedchart in the Spreadsheet Google Apps Script.

```
var chartresult = newsheet.newChart()
      .addRange(plotdata)
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
      .setPosition(5, 4, 1, 1)
      .setOption('title', title)
      .setOption('pointSize', 3)
      .build();
```

However, when I open the spreadsheet, the chart is always shown as a Line Chart. If I open the 'edit chart' window, the 'edit chart' window shows the scatter chart and I have to click 'update chart' to make chart in the spread sheet look right.
Anyone knows if this is a bug or my set up is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: It is not really a line chart, seems to be a mix between line and scatter (lines + dots)... did you notice issues on other types as well ? I tested a few and it seems this is the only one that returns a wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the chart dialog built into the Google Spreadsheets UI is setting some default values that aren't being set when using the EmbeddedChartBuilder. If you manually set lineWidth to zero then the lines will go away.

```
.setOption('lineWidth', 0)
```